# antrun never copies jars

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar" todir="${project.basedir}/../server/plug
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

After `mvn install`, I never see the jarfile copied from target/project.jar to ../server/plugins/project.jar.

Why isn't ant running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [Maven Lifecycle docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) to see a list of the phases in Maven's default lifecycle. Note that `deploy` phase is after `install`.

The above POM shows the plugin execution is bound to the `deploy` phase, but the command run was `mvn install`. So the execution doesn't run.

You will either need to run `mvn deploy`, or change the phase to `install` or earlier phase, to see this command running.